# Category products are gone after installing solr on Magento Enterprise 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalogsearch, solr

I have installed Solr version 3.6.2 on EE 1.14 version of Magento. Solr is working fine, when I visit http://localhost:8983/solr/ , but all category products are disappeared from catalog, and on searching a keyword no result is showing other than related search terms.

I have not set up any schema or Solr docs for this, please provide some suggestions.

Thanks,

Abhilash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution for it. I installed jetty, set the java home path for jetty, and started Jetty. After that did a reindex of Magento using

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

I was able to see all the products.